# How do I tell heroku that my server.js and package.json are inside a folder?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

Currently my file structure looks like this

[image]

As you can see, my server and package files are inside the backend folder. The project-replays folder is the frontend folder.

As expected, when I do `heroku local` on my root folder, it tells me that it cant find a package.json that should be placed on the root folder. Is there a way to tell heroku to look for the package.json inside the backend folder?

Comment: Possible, example: https://github.com/accimeesterlin/mern-stack-deploy-heroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a `package.json` to root, even if it's just for running scripts. Detecting a `package.json` is how the Node buildpack detects a Node app too, so it's a minimum requirement to run Node on Heroku.

You'll want to add something like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node backend/server.js"
}
```

`heroku local` will by default use the `npm start` script at root.

Comment: When I was working on local, I run ```npm start``` from my ```project-replays``` folder. Is there a way to also change that? if it tries to run ```npm start``` from the root folder it will fail right?

Comment: > Is there a way to also change that?
I would set up both start scripts at root then. You could have a `"start-frontend"` script that is something like `cd project-replays && npm start`.
> if it tries to run npm start from the root folder it will fail right?
You'll need a `package.json` at root. Since you are using a few scripts with 2 child directories, I would suggest using a Procfile too: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: but it is asking for the dependencies again and need to copy the dependencies in backend package.json and paste in root package.json